Python outputs Windows fatal exception: code 0x8001010
I have an automation test framework that is using unittest python framework under the hood. It has been producing a segmentation fault. I isolated it to the usage of a DLL library.
I ran my python program with faulthandler enabled to obtain more traceback information on the segmentation fault.
My program was spitting out a bunch of error's but continues to run.
Multiple errors popping up here
    tb_e = traceback.TracebackException(excType, value, tb, limit=length,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\traceback.py", line 502, in __init__
    self.stack = StackSummary.extract(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\traceback.py", line 379, in extract
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\linecache.py", line 72, in checkcache
    stat = os.stat(fullname)
ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path


Finally, at the end of the run I got the output:
Windows fatal exception: code 0x80010108

Thread 0x0000b778 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 185 in _shutdown
Windows fatal exception: code 0x80010108

Thread 0x0000b778 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 185 in _shutdown

Googling shows error code 0x80010108 interpreted as Windows Update Error? This error is quite confusing to me because I am not doing a window's update during this time. How would I continue to debug this issue?

Without a repro, or at least a short description about your program (is it a pytest?) I wouldn't expect a breaktrough soon.

@Trapli I wanted to avoid spraying too much code because it's a large program and lots of mechanics to it. I'll add a description and see if it helps. I was hoping someone would know what the error code means in the context of the library I am using.

The error is mentioning path, is it doing any File IO? Could be handling files or path in a nonagnostic way.

According to this table, that error code corresponds to RPC_E_DISCONNECTED. My impression from searching the internet is that a variety of things can cause this error, and there is no way to know without more information.

@tyleax the reason why I asked for a short description (and specifically "pytest") because I've seen this yesterday: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/858 and if you happen to use pywinauto there could be some info in there for you

@Trapli That is interesting. Thanks for the link. I do have use of from pywinauto.application import Application but the specific test scripts I ran is not using it. I guess importing is sufficient now to cause the issue. However I am not using pytest. I'll explore disabling to see if this fixes the problem. From the article I realized I can also enable logging for comtypes to see if there is any more clues I can gather.

@Trapli Removing pywinauto got rid of the exception at the end of run on the application. Can you post a proper answer and I can set it as the answer? Thanks.

there you go :)

The described problem is very similar with this Open github issue:
https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/858
If you happen to use pywinauto, reading the thread may worth your time. It seems that there are certain python and windows version combinations which trigger the issue described above.
To get rid of the problem you can try:

experiment with the software versions (python 32 bit -> 64 bit, or different comtypes/pywinauto library versions and see if anything works)
or avoid using pywinauto until the problem is fixed (right now it is a 3 year old issue)
or if you don't use pywinauto directly but you use pytest, you can run your tests with the -p no:faulthandler parameter

